# datadog monitor hold alert to allow time to self resolve

Tags: monitor, datadog

Is there an easy way to datadog monitors to hold alerts to allow time for the cloud to self resolve?

My team often gets alerted for monitors that self resolve before we have a chance to address it. If datadog could hold the alert for 5-10 minutes we would avoid unactionable alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the alert window to be longer.

[image: time selector in metric monitor]

Comment: if there was a spike that recovers quickly, the alert would still end up going out to the team. 
I would like to allow for a spike but only send an alert if it does not come down within x minutes.

Comment: Change the threshold from "on average" to "at all times"

Comment: it seems I cannot change the threshold from "on average" to "at all times"

is it because of the metric I chose? 

avg:azure.sql_servers_databases.connection_failed{environment:production} by {server_name,name}.as_count()

Comment: I just spoke to Datadog support ,  they have removed the "at all times" feature from the monitors. it looks like the "minimum" option is the substitute